# Magento - Display Second Product Image

Tags: php, magento

I am using the below code to display the main product image:

```
$productId = $this->getProduct_id(); 
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
?>

<div class="single-image-large" onclick='window.open("<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>", "_self")'>
    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><img class="blog-image" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(400, 400) ?>" width="400" height="400" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" /><span class="img-caption"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></span></a>
</div>
```

I would like to edit it so that it shows the product's second image.  Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I feel you can fetch the other images by using

```
$_product->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label', 'LABEL_NAME')->getUrl();
```

or fetch the whole gallery and display it as per your requirement

```
Mage::getModel(’catalog/product’)->load($productId)->getMediaGalleryImages();
```